# Помогите с кешированием

Tags: битрикс

Код представлен ниже. Понимаю, что ничего особенного за кешированием нет, но пока не могу правильно заполнить. Кто может подсказать, что не так?

Ошибка вываливается при вызове `$сache->startDataCache();`

Пробовал "управляемый" кеш, тоже не работает.

```
<?
$cur_path=array_slice(
    explode(
        '/',
        $APPLICATION->GetCurPage()
    ),
    count(
        explode(
            '/',
            $arParams['PATH']
        )
    ) + 1
);

$cache = Bitrix\Main\Data\Cache::createInstance();

$cache_id = 'main' . $cur_path[0].$cur_path[1];

if ($cache->initCache(3600, $cache_id)) {

    $result = $сache->getVars(); 

    $this->IncludeComponentTemplate();

}
else {
    $сache->startDataCache();
    CModule::IncludeModule("iblock");

    include $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/bitrix/components/zebrains/catalog/lib.php';

    $arResult=arResult(
        $arParams,
        $cur_path
    );

    if ($arResult == 404) {
        $cache->abortDataCache();
        echo 404;
    } else {
        $cache->endDataCache($arResult);

        $this->IncludeComponentTemplate();
    }
}
```

Ошибка:

```
[Error] 
Call to a member function startDataCache() on null (0)
/var/www/bitrix.site/bitrix/components/zebrains/catalog/component.php:57
```

---

Всем спасибо, проблема решилась, случайно с вместо си вписал.

Comment: Здесь нет телепатов и предсказателей. Какая ошибка-то? Или надо самому догадаться, что вам выводится?

Comment: Описание ошибки даже телепату не поможет. Такая: [Error] 
Call to a member function startDataCache() on null (0)
/var/www/bitrix.site/bitrix/components/zebrains/catalog/component.php:57

Comment: Ну-у-у, написал же ошибку.

Comment: Попробуйте передать в startDataCache необязательные параметры: время жизни, id,

Comment: Пробовал. Ошибка не меняется.

Comment: А что приходит в переменную  cache_id? Там строка как положено?

Comment: строка. Буквы, цифры и "-".

Comment: Если вопрос был вызван опечаткой, наврядли он кому-то поможет. Его стоит удалить.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте вот так. С живого проекта, код рабочий

```
$cache = Bitrix\Main\Data\Cache::createInstance();

$TTL = $arParams['CACHE_TIME']; // в вашем случае 3600, но я бы рекомендовал использовать arParams
$uniqueString = __FILE__;
$initDir = '/path/to/cache';

if ($cache->initCache($TTL, $uniqueString, $initDir)) {

        $arResult = $cache->getVars();

} elseif ($cache->startDataCache()) {
   //....
}

$this->IncludeComponentTemplate();
```